# jquery Как добавить элемент после найденого

Tags: javascript, jquery

Например есть такой код

```
<div>
   <div onclick = "$(this).parent().append('<div>text1.5</div>');">text1</div>
   <div>text2</div>
</div>
```

При клике у меня будит следующий результат

```
<div>
   <div onclick = "$(this).parent().append('<div>text1.5</div>');">text1</div>
   <div>text2</div>
   <div>text1.5</div>
</div>
```

Но мне нужно чтоб страница стала такой

```
<div>
   <div onclick = "$(this).parent().append('<div>text1.5</div>');">text1</div>
   <div>text1.5</div>
   <div>text2</div>
</div>
```

Как такое реализовать ?

если кратко, то как мне добавить новый элемент после найденного а не в найденный как делает следующая функция

```
$(this).append('<div>text1.5</div>');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы разместить элемент после определённого элемента, Вы можете использовать `after`.
Пример:

```html
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div>
    <div onclick = "$(this).after('<div>text1.5</div>');">text1</div>
    <div>text2</div>
</div>
```